# How to set different Style of ListBoxItem with different data model binded to the ListBox in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have one `ListBox`. I set its `ItemSource` with Collection of my custom data called `Book`. But `Book` is general type, and it has different type, like `Novel`, `ScienceBook`, etc. So what I want is to set different style for its `ListBoxItem`. For example: setting the red color of the title of `Book` if it is instance of `Novel`, and set the others to be blue color.
How can I achieve this in Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More elegant way is to define [DataTemplateSelector](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector) to choose which `DataTemplate` will be used for which item

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found the answer of my question. The solution is just create the middle data model providing information about the style to be used. In xaml, I just add attribute `Style={Binding Style}`. Hope it will help others.